# Cryptic Country 2

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I'm a seven out of ten, that's kind of easy to see

A beef dish has given a capital name just to me

Made of two in the water, next to two in one

Add an English dialect and you are just about done

Name the country

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you

> New Zealand?

I'm a seven out of ten, that's kind of easy to see

> Because the two islands (kind of) look like a number 7?

A beef dish has given a capital name just to me

> Beef Wellington, as Wellington is the capital of NZ

Made of two in the water, next to two in one

> Made of the North and South Islands, and is right beside Australia (big landmass + Tasmania)

Add an English dialect and you are just about done

> They sure do speak some funny sounding English in Australia/NZ!